# Deny access to certain class files in a dependency jar

Tags: java, dependencies

I have to include a jar file because I need certain classes in it in my dynamic web project.

My problem is that this jar contains an old version of *apache.commons.io*. BUT in my dynamic web project I have also included a *newer* version of *apache.commons.io*.

Now I want to avoid java to use the old version of *apache.commons.io* in my dynamic web project. Is there any way to tell java not to use classes in a certain folder in my jar?

Comment: Can't you just remove the conflicting classes? Jar is a zip file, it's trivial.

Comment: Hi Karol, thanks for your hint. I'm writing a hadoop application where the jar is distributed to a cluster during runtime so the jar has to remain untouched.

Comment: Edit the jar file before you deploy to Hadoop.

Comment: Hi Elliott, thanks for your answer. I'd like to find a configurational solution first. Nevertheless, adding the necessary jar's would be a solution.