# How to exclude a specific jar from java classpath

Tags: java, dynamic, classpath

I am using this below structure to set classpath in my java application.
How can I exclude a specific jar that is loading in runtime.

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java
PATH=/usr/local/java/bin:${PATH}
cd /home/ala/DevDaily/Musubi

THE_CLASSPATH=
for i in `ls ./lib/*.jar`
do
  THE_CLASSPATH=${THE_CLASSPATH}:${i}
done
```

Comment: i dont think its possible to exclude dependent jars.

Comment: I have a method implementation in two jars. my application is taking wrong jar, If I totally remove the wrong jar, it is picking up the correct implementation jar. But I can not completely remove that jar, I have other dependencies. I need to exclude the wrong implementation for this specific method only. is there anyway to do so?

Comment: could you please tell what is the jar for ??

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this similar question can help you?
[Deny access to certain class files in a dependency jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588367/deny-access-to-certain-class-files-in-a-dependency-jar)

If your case is more complex, and you have another dependency which needs the 'old' implementation of the method and you cannot modify it another solution might be to update the class in the older jar with a 'smarter' class which can hold two implementations dependent on your two callers.

The following code will obtain and print the name of the caller's package and class, after which you can decide your different behaviors.

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
String name = stackTrace[1].getClassName();
System.out.println(name);
```

This solution is incredibly ill-advised, and defeats the entire purpose of the jar, but it might be a quick fix to your problem.